# Searching for string in string in Couchbase

Tags: go, couchbase

I'm using the [GO SDK](https://docs.couchbase.com/go-sdk/1.5/full-text-searching-with-sdk.html) to search my Couchbase database. I have this **exact** match query working:

```
qp.And(cbft.NewConjunctionQuery(cbft.NewMatchQuery("garden").Field("Features")))
```

But I want to do use a '`LIKE`' query instead. For example, find "garden" in this string "driveway, garden, shed".

How do I do that in Go?

Comment: Just to clarify, because I don't know Go: A `LIKE` would involve writing N1QL. But your code looks to be using a FTS index? A match query should match words exactly already, but it looks like you're conjoining it with something else. Could you provide some more detail and show a complete minimum example?

Comment: I don't know enough about how the GO SDK works, but based on a cursory glance, I'd look at NewWildCardQuery method: `...cbft.NewWildCardQuery("*garden*")...`

Comment: @JerodJohnson Unless I'm mistaken wildcard searches can't work before the word. So `...cbft.NewWildCardQuery("ga*den*")...` would work, but that doesn't help.